# How can I add a facebook like button to my application in Java

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-like, jeditorpane

I have found this question here:

[Is it possible to add a facebook like button on a Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870665/is-it-possible-to-add-a-facebook-like-button-on-a-java-application)

Here is an example of the code generated for Microsoft's page.

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fmicrosoft&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Although you can also just specify a URL and it takes you to the same page:

http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fmicrosoft&width&layout=button_count&action=like&show_faces=false&share=false&height=21

How can I create a WebBrowser object initialised with this code so that the user can click my button?

JEditorPane messes up the display. Can you recommend another component?
Regards.

Comment: So, one thing i notice is that the page isn't just html, it has lots of other stuff on it like javascript.  Have you tried doing it with a basic HTML page to see if that will load?

Comment: Ye i need HTML5 to display the like button correctly. JEditorPane only supports up to HTML 3.2

Comment: You could use a `JButton` with a custom image and an `ActionEvent` that uses `Desktop`'s `browse(URI)`.

Comment: Don't think this is helpful, but you can get an instance of the JavaScript engine in Java with `ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");`